# Accessing a library (compiled using higher jdk) gives exception when accessed from lower JRE

Tags: eclipse, jvm, java

I created a jar file (compiled it using jdk1.7). When I used this jar in a project(using JRE 1.6), I get the following exception- unsupported major.minor version 51.0 (I suppose 51.0 is meant for jdk1.7). I used eclipse IDE for all these operations.

I am wondering whether this exception is a norm (in this kind of situation) or is it coming just because class loading in eclipse works differently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected. Bytecode specifically compiled for a java version, can't be executed on a lower version. This is because it might have bytecode instructions and/or features not supported by an earlier Java version.

To compile for a lower java version, you need to explicitly specify the target version of compilation, eg:

```
javac -target 1.6 ...
```

In Eclipse you can set this under Properties > Java Compiler > "Generated .class files compatibility". However in general it is advisable to just use a Java 6 compiler to make sure you are actually only using features and libraries included in Java 6.

Comment: So, basically eclipse is not the culprit (classloading in eclipse is different, it uses multiple class loaders), and this exception is likely to come in this kind of situation, is that right?

Comment: This will happen with any Java virtual machine when it is asked to load a class compiled for a higher version.

Answer (score 1):

Class loading is performed by the JVM, both within eclipse and outside of it. This error simply indicates the the file format of class files has changed in Java 7, and a Java 6 virtual machine does't know the class file format from the future.

You can instruct the Java compiler to use the class file format of a previous java version (in eclipse, you can find the setting under Properties -> Java Compiler -> JDK compliance).

In addition, you'll want to verify that you only use API elements that also existed in JDK 6.